# the property of two matrices to be commutative is not transitive

Tags: calculus, matrices

it is known that a square matrix **A** may commute with **B**, and that the same matrix  **A** may commute with **C**, but **B** and **C** do not commute. This is true only if all the matrices are derogatory, see for example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices

My question is the following: which may be a procedure to generate the matrices A, B, and C which are so non-diagonalisables and have the shown property ?
If some body may give me some tips or indicate a bibliographical reference, it will be fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is true if the matrices are derogatory? what does that mean? why do you want the matrices to be non-diagonalisable?

Comment: this means that in the case of diagonalisables matrices, such a procedure is well known... but this is not an answer to my question. Thank you

Comment: sorry, big mistake in the previous assertion... it means that for diagonalisables matrices, the commutative property is also transitive, so for these matrices if A commutes with B and A commutes with C, than B will commute with C... so for this reason I adress this particular case

Comment: no, commutativity is not transitive for diagonalisable matrices. Just take two noncommuting matrices and notice that both commute with the identity

Comment: @thedude what if we remove the case that $B$ is a scalar matrix?